# Is the constructor logic code smell dependent on the type of code or quantity?

Tags: design-patterns, constructor

Logic in a constructor is a code smell. However, is it the quantity of code in a constructor which is bad or the type of code (is there certain code which would be allowed in a constructor?)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor's main purpose is to validate the context of the object creation (parameters, environment...) and to initialize the instance before any method can be called.

For instance, one of FileStream's constructors takes a file path and file mode in parameter and will throw an exception if the file does not exist.

IMO, as long as your code is validation/initialization logic, it is perfectly valid in a constructor even if it represents a lot of code. What could be fishy is code in a constructor that is not related to the validation of the context or the initialization of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the code could potentially raise an exception is one thing I avoid in constructors.  I try to limit constructor code to strictly initialize the object, and only in cases where default values won't do - and that doesn't come up too often.